# Missing a comma issue?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, arrow-functions

I have this code:

```
pell.init({
    element: ma_visual_divs[i],

    actions: [
        'bold',
        {
            name: 'custom',
            icon: 'C',
            title: 'Custom Action',
            //result: () => pell.exec('formatBlock', '<P>')
        },
        'underline'
    ],

})
```

Whenever I add the line `result: () => pell.exec('formatBlock', '<P>')` into the code, I see an error in my editor stating that a comma is missing:

[image]

How exactly do I add the `result` line into the code without triggering error? Feel free to test it on your own editor to see the issue.

Comment: What editor? Is it running linting? What's your linting setup for commas?

Comment: Is it possible one of the apostrophes isn't an apostrophe, and just looks like one?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am using PHPstorm.

Comment: If you guys insert the above code into your own editors and uncomment the result line, you will see the error.

Comment: My editor doesn't yield any error. jsfiddle.net doesn't either.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't complain.

Comment: See this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/kW5XmXg.png)

Comment: It looks like your editor doesn't know arrow function syntax.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson No, across multiple editors, this code will not create any warnings--in general making assumptions about what editors people are using or how they're set up will lead to frustration. Looks more like it's not handling ES6 arrow functions given the other squiggles. Once it doesn't know something, until it "catches up", all sorts of things may be considered wrong.

Comment: Does [this help you?](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/javascript/es6-find-doesnt-work) Related [Ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16444).

Answer (score 2):

This is a valid syntax.

The editor problem can have several reasons:

1. Your IDE does not use the ES6+ syntax. Solution: Go to settings -> Languages and Frameworks -> Javascript and change the version to ECMAscript 6 (In Webstorm). As you are using PHPStorm it can differ a bit, check the docs: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/node-js.html
2. You are using lint tool. Check the package.json, if you see "eslint" package there, your project has probably some special rules about how the code should look like. One rule is https://eslint.org/docs/rules/comma-dangle I recommend to have always comma at the end, it is much better when you move/add some other fields and it does not break on merge requests.
3. Make sure your Node.js is at least version 6 (try `node --version`).